# Wordpress redirects to backend when i'am not logged in

Tags: redirect

When I open my main url (https://ausbildung.sikler.de) something automatically redirects to the backend (https://ausbildung.sikler.de/UP1/wp-login.php?redirect_to=%2F
When I log in I can see the page (with the Wordpress bar on top).
UP1 is the location of WordPress.

I already deleted the .htaccess files but nothing changes.

Comment: do you have the correct settings in admin > settings > general (Wordpress Address & Site Address)?

Comment: WordPress-Adresse (URL) = https://ausbildung.sikler.de/UP1
Website-Adresse (URL) = https://ausbildung.sikler.de

On Server the Structure is as follows: /www/sikler/ausbildung/UP1
Where /ausbildung/ only contains the wp-config.php and index.php and (seems to redirect) to /UP1/ where all the WordPress files are.